# How to create a temporary table for an existing table with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I have a table(in mysql-server) associated with the following class:

```
class Number(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'number'
    col0 = Column(...) # PRIMARY KEY
    col1 = Column(...)
    col2 = Column(...)
    col3 = Column(...)
```

I want to create a temporary table for this number table when the program starts, this temporary table looks like:

```
class tempNumber(Base):
      __table_name__ = 'temp_number'
      col0 = Column(...) # direct from Number.col0
      col1 = Column(...) # from Number.col1, but will be modified, for example tempNumber.col1 = Number.col1.replace(' ','')
```

I also tried  to add the following line to class Number:

```
__table_args__ = {'prefixes': ['TEMPORARY']}
```

but my python programm told me that table temp_number doesn't exist.

and one more question is, how to copy the data fast? because there are lots of rows in table number.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the `temp_number` table actually exist in the underlying database?
2. Generally, copying data from one table to another quickly isn't done through `sqlalchemy`, which has significant overhead in this type of task. Instead, it will vary depending on your underlying database.

For example, [here's how one would do it in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482443/how-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-in-mysql). [Here's a way to do it with PostgreSQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601978/completely-copying-a-postgres-table-with-sql)  However, this usually doesn't copy things like indexes. That, you'll have to setup manually, via your database driver.