# Include references while copying a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a database called `contests` whose copy I want to create
Referring to the top answer for this question : [Copy a table (including indexes) in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198141/copy-a-table-including-indexes-in-postgres)
I executed the following command :
`create table contests_clean ( like contests INCLUDING ALL );`
It did create a new table with the `modifiers` and `indexes` as viewed in `\d contests` in the database but it did not copy the references (`Referenced by` as viewed in `\d contests` )
What do I need to add to the command to include `References` as well (`Referenced by` as viewed in `\d contests`
Please ask for any further details that are required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Referenced by" means that another table references `contests`, i.e. there is a foreign key constraint in the referencing table pointing to `contests`.

So you cannot really "copy" that along with `contents` but had to either change the foreign key constraints in the referencing tables pointing to the new table or copy the referencing tables and then change their foreign key constraints.